# How to pass String to constructor from a map

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an Athlet Object from a DocumentSnapshot. In this DocumentSnapshot I have stored a map, that holds the values(i.E. "upperbody": 0), to this athletes favourite Categorys. But for the AthleteObject I only need the key, of the category with the highest Value.
This should work, but I get the following error. And I dont' know how to rewrite this for it to not complain.

The instance member 'getFavCategory' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Documentation)  Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

```
Athlete.fromJSON(DocumentSnapshot parsedJSON):
        _name = parsedJSON["name"],
        _rank = parsedJSON['rank'],
        _xp = parsedJSON['xp'],
        _foot = parsedJSON['foot'],
        _position = parsedJSON['position'],
        _statsDate = parsedJSON['statsDate'],
        _challengeCount = parsedJSON['challengeCount'],
        _workoutCount = parsedJSON['workoutCount'],
        _favCategory = getFavCategory(parsedJSON['favCategory']),
        _shotsTaken = parsedJSON['shotsTaken'],
        _shotsMade = parsedJSON['shotsMade'],
        _passesTaken = parsedJSON['passesTaken'],
        _passesMade = parsedJSON['passesMade'];

  String getFavCategory(Map<String, dynamic> map){
    String favCat;
    int maxVal;
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      if(maxVal == null || value > maxVal){
        maxVal = value;
        favCat = key;
      }
    });
    return favCat;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of **getFavCategory** states that it has to be called on an initialized instance of your Athlete class (which is not a case for your constructor).

The fastest you can do is simply turn your **getFavCategory** function in to static (since you are not using any class variables inside):

```dart
static String getFavCategory(Map<String, dynamic> map){
    String favCat;
    int maxVal;
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      if(maxVal == null || value > maxVal){
        maxVal = value;
        favCat = key;
      }
    });
    return favCat;
  }
```